# ARM ACLE support in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, cortex-m

I'm writing an application where I'd like to detect whether a function is called from an ISR. Ignoring the specifics of the application it is targeting a Cortex M0. In an effort to avoid having to use `asm` tags directly I wanted to use the ARM ACLE implementations to make the code a little easier to read. As such using the `__arm_rsr` function seemed like a reasonable function to use. Just to test I put together a simple application in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcYl2mA4ZQgRMxARZPn4BldUCtfUERRHRsQm2dQ1NOa1D3aG9pf3xAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJutu9SwA%2BkzbmAB0CAfYJhoAgvcPoQS7LEyhELP78VaPu0Buy8r3WZhObwILCS%2B3WABFdiczsRTsQFMQIOYzABJZRCABKWNmB3%2BTwBQOImAISwYuw0JOeJnicI481onAArLw/BwtKRUJw3NZrLsFItlph9mZ1jxSARNKz5gBrEDrAAcly4ZjMkkkaoAnPF9Rz9Vw1dJ2RxJNyFfzOLwFCANHKFfM4LAYIgUKhoXRYuRKGhffQ4scuBozM6aLQCLFHRAoraoqF6gBPTiyoNsQQAeQYtHTvN4WA%2BRnERdI%2BEp1QAbphHRXMKoql5YxneK9MJa%2BbQ8FFiGmPFhbQRiHgWK6%2BAZgAoAGp4TAAdxzSUY7ZkghEYnYUg38iUaltunW%2BkMxmFln0fcdkHmqCSjgEDYAtCxkEkvAc4WgGk3X3y2kfPwIFcEY/C4QIGHQHoSjKPQUjSICwPg/IgJgvo4ggwCanGZCsK7KogM6Bp0OmTDBi6PCKJIyZYP6Lh5jFJYVj0UdMFWHg2U5G0KwFDgHnxABZXZgGQZBdniS4zE1XYIAYARMB%2BCAhUsaxSF2XBCBIKUZXUjxg1iHT1lmXh5SLWZlVVdZLnWWy7Ps%2ByADZ9E4a1SAnWybIc7zbNIHk%2BT4h0nRdczSHdL0gySP0yAoCBIuikBjhreJn22M8uHDCDo1jNFKETCtk2YYhC0zH1swIPMC1tEsz3LPkq0IvA6wbPkmxbNtuA7QQu1tXt%2B0HDBVj5Udx0nKhpznBdl1XHlZX4TdRHEXd5v3FR1ArXQLTPFALxsPqb2%2BfkHwyF83w/L8f1jVR/wdAj2mA0DPGaPRglojCUMQjIqIQgoGFIuD8PsIjcKenJAcajpxn%2B%2BjqMaUHwNh6HMMY8UWIgtiONZFyOC5PzbT41RHMkd4FBrcSay4fVNWJiAAHVsXCbAlJUqxLw0/AiGIHSIN2fSopDHTJBMkKtAs0gEEwJgsDiQ7LTcjzrJ8ny8d4%2B1bGCszRbCz0ICQRYCA/AgAzin1%2Bf6E9MA5kg9BWrclukFbFDWkdKUx0hFwHJJ2y4nGeICzgc1bQ3dlQKhdgE4TRPE8MpNk3sGC8VRmdN6KjOFzXFWx%2BWrK8pX7JV/2OCC50M7FlVHK4S41XieIOQ5cNI0kDQ1S4ZzLXWP3eECkXM8tMxO7tIue7Fus0QyEBJCAA) just to test the basics of it but to my surprise it fails to compile. According to [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-C-Language-Extensions-_0028ACLE_0029.html) themselves, they support ARM ACLE v1.1 completely. According to [ARM](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101028/0002?lang=en) themselves `__arm_rsr` is defined in ACLE v1.1. As a control I decided to just double check with Clang and that compiled just fine. Am I just missing something obvious or does GCC simply not support any version of ARM ACLE completely?

The test application:

```cpp
#include <arm_acle.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t tmp = __arm_rsr("IPSR");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, looks like a it is not implemented enough.

Comment: How have they managed to miss implementing it? Seems like that should be caught in some unit test or in a PR.

Comment: Seems like. I think make a bug report and see what happens. TBH looks like a great opportunity to get into gcc development and create a PR yourself to gcc with the implementation.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is a good idea to do that. However; I'd rather not need to use a custom fork of GCC for the production code I am writing so I'd like a quicker solution. I'll have a look around to see if I can find a more immediate solution.

Comment: `I'd like a quicker solution` so just use `__get_IPSR`, I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

My arm-none-eabi-gcc (8.3.1) has `arm_acle.h` but not `__arm_rsr`.

The normal way to do this is use `__get_IPSR()`.

This is defined in `cmsis_gcc.h`, but don't include that directly because it requires certain macros to be defined first.  Include the appropriate CMSIS header for your device, eg: `#include "stm32f4xx.h"`.

Comment: That's not gonna work out of the box for me, but thank you for the heads up. However, GCC should still implement the the missing functionality.

Comment: The existing gcc developers probably aren't interested in spending any time on this when there is a perfectly good alternative that works for everyone else.  Of course gcc is open source so if you care about it more than they do you can make the changes yourself and submit a patch :-).